# iPhone Safari - too many redirects error

Tags: iphone, wordpress, .htaccess, safari, mobile-safari

I have a client who is currently receiving a 'too many redirects' error from Safari on her iPhone 4.  I have tested on other iPhones, including the 4, and do not get this error.  Any experience with this? It's a wordpress site, Go-Daddy hosted.. I have a few additions to my HTACCESS file but nothing crazy.

I know she might be able to resolve the issue by clearing her browser's cookies, but if it is an issue that could potentially affect other iPhone users and is being caused by something on my end, I would like to prevent the issue from occurring in the future..

Any suggestions?

*Edit* Here is the htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 /Testimonials.html /testimonials/
Redirect 301 /Wedding_Accessories.html /dyeable-shoes-bride-on-a-budget/
Redirect 301 /Wedding_Shoes_Styles.php /shoes/
Redirect 301 /Custom_Shoes.html /custom-shoes/
Redirect 301 /Custom_Wedding_Sashes.php /custom-sashes/
Redirect 301 /Wedding_Album.php /gallery/
Redirect 301 /Customizable_shoe_styles.php /custom-shoes/
Redirect 301 /Home_Page.html /
Redirect 301 /Custom_Shoe_Inquiry.html /custom-shoes/
Redirect 301 /comments/feed/ /
Redirect 301 /Etsy_Shop.html /shoes/
Redirect 301 /about/terms/ /terms-and-conditions/
Redirect 301 /Dyeable_Shoes.html /shoes/
Redirect 301 /about/privacy/ /example-privacy-policy/
Redirect 301 /faqs/ /FAQs/
Redirect 301 /ShoeNews.html /blog/
Redirect 301 /About_Us.html /about-us/

# BEGIN wtwp_cache
# END wtwp_cache

# BEGIN wtwp_security
# END wtwp_security
```

Comment: Usually a "too many redirects" error results from some kind of endless redirection loop. Have you analyzed the server logs?

Comment: Yes. Post the relevant code where the loop might be generated.

Comment: I've added the contents of HTAcccess, I have only added some redirects for pages that used to exist.  But then again, it's possible I've done something wrong as I don't usually dabble with this. Just tested another iphone, loaded up fine (client still having issues).

Comment: I'm also looking into the logs.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Your `Redirect` statements should go before your WordPress rewrites, otherwise you are going to get a 404 error for them. You might want to try and reset your rewrite_rules by going to WP Admin > Settings > Permalinks and hitting save again.

Comment: @doublesharp - I've moved the redirects before the WP rewrites as per your suggestion.  Catastrophic failure did not ensue.. I assume you were correct about the placement then ;D  I'll get back with whether this fixed the issue on the iPhone in question. *Update* Apparently this did not help fix the issue on the offending iPhone.

Comment: Did you try re-saving your permalinks, thats what I think might do it? I wouldn't expect the re-order to fix it, but it would be correct to do it for other reasons.

Comment: @doublesharp - yes, I did re-save the permalinks as well.